# Notation of infinite product of banach algebras

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

[image: .]

Here they define product for countable many. But how to define the that product for uncountable many banach algebras. I am unable to find it anywhere that's why I am posting it here. Below I found a excercise where it does not mention about the index that's why I am wondering.
[image: .]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can defined by:
$\{x\in\prod_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i: \forall \epsilon>0, \{i: \|x(i)\|>\epsilon\} \text{ is finite } \}$

Or we may consider $I$ as a discrete topological space, and $x$ are those sections that vanish at infinity.

Comment: I get the first definition. But what is section and what dp you mean by vanish at infinity?

Comment: Any topological space $X$ has the one-point compatification, and a function $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is said to vanish at infinity if $\tilde f(\infty)=0$ is a continuous extension of $f$ to $X\cup\{\infty\}$. In the case of $X$ being finite, a neighborhood of $\infty$ is just the complement of a finite set. Hence the definition from the first line.

Comment: We used the word "section", because the range of $f$ varies from point to point in $I$, and the proper way to think about this is each $\mathcal A_i$ is a "fibre" over the point, and for each point, we take a point from the fibre will form a "section"  (In general, we would like $f$ to be continuous from fibre to fibre, here we don't have any "gluing" information of the $\mathcal A_i$'s, and we don't need them, as $I$ is discrete, hence the fibres don't communicate with each other). This is common in topology and algebraic geometry.